# Convert Unicode to string Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Unicode character to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090585/convert-unicode-character-to-nsstring)

After parsing data from a website, the result was an object that contains Unicode and I want to convert it to NSString (the Unicode contains Hebrew  characters mostly).

Here is some (small fraction) of the Unicode in the Log:

"\U05f3\U009e\U05f3\U00a2\U05f3\U2022"

How can I convert it?

Comment: The problem is that most of the characters that I'm converting from is in Hebrew so it's a different problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into data and then to string.

```
char *yourObject=...;
NSData *unicodeData=[NSData dataWithBytes:yourObject
                                     length:strlen(yourObject)];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodeData           
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks, when I'm converting an Hebrew char it shows a dot instead of a character, any idea how can I convert it properly?

Comment: Sorry I cant find the solution, you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c