# UTF8 encoding in NSString

Tags: ios

I used the following code to encode unicode character "\u1000" into UTF8 encoding.

```
NSString *unicodeString = @"\u1000";
NSLog(@"%s", [unicodeString UTF8String]);
```

The expected result would be \u00e1\u0080\u0080 but I am getting \U00b7\U00c4\U00c4.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Unicode character to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090585/convert-unicode-character-to-nsstring)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a unichar value to an NSString in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c)