# Compare two arabic words

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unicode

I have a JSON data in unicode (like: \u0661\u0660) that I am displaying in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I need to make the cell of different color when the `value` key from json is `"عشرة  ١٠"`.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

_params = [[json valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"list"];
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *match = @"عشرة  ١٠";
item = [[_params objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"value"];
```

Is there a way to compare `match` 
with `item`? The containsString, localizedStandardContainsString do not work.

Comment: Did you try `[match isEqualToString: item]`?

Comment: Point is the text from json is in unicode so 'item' is originally : \u0639\u0634\u0631\u0629 \u0661\u0660

Answer (score 0):

You can convert unicode to NSString and than compare it,

refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943928/convert-unicode-string-to-nsstring) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090759/6742121)

After converting it to string you can simply check it by,

```
[your_string isEqualToString:@"your second string"];
```

Hope this will help you.